# react-native-video: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use [react-native-video](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video) in a project but when I run it I get `Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined` on a red screen in the iOS simulator.

I can reproduce with a very simple test app:

```
> react-native init MyApp
> cd MyApp
> npm install react-native-video --save
> rnpm link react-native-video
```

Add `import Video from 'react-native-video';` or `var Video = require('react-native-video');` to `index.ios.js` after other imports.

```
> react-native run-ios
```

[image: The error]

Here's [Video.js](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video/blob/17811e29f876482ae8abe291ea6f1e60bf12fc9b/Video.js). Via `console.log` I can see that `Component` is undefined. That would explain the error but I don't know what to do about it.

Versions Installed:

- react@15.0.2
- react-native@0.26.1
- react-native-video@0.7.1
- react-native-cli@0.2.0

Comment: just tried, and it works fine. the only difference is that "react-native-video" version is: "^0.8.0-rc"

Comment: You're right. I installed yesterday and got 0.7.1. Now I get 0.8.0-rc and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I had to upgrade react-native-video

I'm not really familiar with npm so maybe there's an easier way. It seemed that trying to upgrade wasn't enough. Maybe the `-rc` was stopping npm from recognising `0.8.0-rc` as an upgrade to `0.7.1`

- `npm remove react-native-video`
- `npm update`
- remove `"react-native-video": "^0.7.1"` from `package.json`
- `npm install react-native-video --save`